# How to test two security adapters on different ports

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-test

Why my application responds with 401 when launched, but my tests give me 200?

I have two security adapters in my application. Here are them:

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@Order(1)
public class ActuatorSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.httpBasic().and().requestMatcher(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint()).authorizeRequests((request) -> {
      request.anyRequest().permitAll();
    });
  }
}

@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@Order(2)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  public void configure(final WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    super.configure(web);
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);
  }
}
```

The actuator adapter is here to open all endpoints. Here is my application.yml:

```
spring:
  gson:
    serialize-nulls: false
  http:
    converters:
      preferred-json-mapper: gson
  jmx:
    enabled: false
  jpa:
    open-in-view: false

br:
  com:
    estevaodias:
      geekish:
        values:
          version: "@project.version@"

management:
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: always
      show-components: always
  endpoints:
    jmx:
      exposure:
        exclude: "*"
    web:
      base-path: /monitoring
      exposure:
        include: "*"
  server:
    port: 8088
```

The last file in this project is the main class. Here it is:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Slf4j
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
public class GeekishApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

  @Value("${br.com.estevaodias.geekish.values.version}")
  private String version;

  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(GeekishApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Override
  public void run(final String... args) throws Exception {
    log.info("Running version {}", version);
  }
}
```

So, when I do a curl to http://localhost:8080/ I face 401.

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'http://localhost:8080/' -UseBasicParsing -Method GET | ConvertTo-Json
Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'http://localhost:8080/' -UseBasicParsing -Met ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

And when I do a curl for http://localhost:8088/monitoring I face 200.

Everything is fine till here.

But, when I check if a request to http://localhost:8080/ will return 401, it returns 200.

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ContextConfiguration(classes = GeekishApplication.class)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
class WebSecurityConfigurationTest {

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Test
  public void givenUrl_whenSendGetForEntityRequest_thenUnauthorized() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/")).andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());
  }
}

[ERROR]   WebSecurityConfigurationTest.givenUrl_whenSendGetForEntityRequest_thenUnauthorized:27 
Expected: <401 UNAUTHORIZED>
     but: was <200 OK>
```

Why?

Comment: Before you ask, I've also triad with TestRestTemplate. 
var response = testRestTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:8080/", String.class);
assertThat(response.getStatusCode(), equalTo(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED));

Comment: What is the purpose of the second `WebSecurityConfiguration` ? From the example you posted it's also doing nothing

Comment: The second one is securing all endpoints. I'm postponing any rules it is going to define. The actuator one is opening /monitoring over port 8088.

Comment: can you try to remove `exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class}` from your Spring Boot annotation? As you provide your own `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` the auto-configuration will back-off for this